# Stopping queued updates to firebase

Tags: firebase

I have what appear to be an infinite write operation that is happening on my firebase data. It could be queued firebase writes that where a result of some sort of loop ( I have not identified the source. Not 100% certain it is on my side ).  How can I stop the updates?  It is rendering the firebase unusable because my client side subscriptions to that firebase also now continually fire because it is receiving the changes.

Any help here?  It seems this scenario should have been encountered before but I could not find anything.  How to force purge queued writes?

Comment: So the updates stopped.   Its not clear the source or the reason it stopped (client side stopped updating or the queued msgs were all applied) but regardless it might be a needed feature to "bring the database down".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This occurs when you have two listeners on the same path, and they are both reading changes, manipulating the data, then writing it back.

Most often, this happens with libs like Backbone or Angular.js, because at some point, an operation removes or adds a key to the data and then sends the "changed" request back. This causes the two listeners to get into an argument about the correct value and keep overwriting each other.

This can happen with multiple clients connected or even with one client that has multiple listeners on the same path.

The simplest way to stop the writes is to temporarily set `".write": false` in your security rules, which will abort the looping processes. Then you can revert the security rules and explore the bug until you ferret out the root cause.

Comment: Thanks.  I had not thought of the security rules.